# CosmosDB Emulator - Create/Delete Databases and Containers using some scripting

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I would like to be able to Create/Delete Databases and Containers from my CosmosDB Emulator using some scripting type. Sometimes I need to do a clean slate, and it's painful to do it manually.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help